# Connect to an Access Point using IWCONFIG

Tags: linux

I have done the follow steps.

- **sudo ifconfig wlan0 up**
- **sudo iwlist wlan0 scan** (I see my access point without problem)

then...

- **sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid MY_ESSID key s:MY_PASSWORD**

I get the follow error:

```
 Error for wireless request "Set
 Encode" (8B2A) :
     SET failed on device wlan0 ; Invalid argument.
```

I used **s:** because I want to pass and ASCII password.

What is the error?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to connect to an access point which is advertising wpa-psk/wpa2-psk? If you trying to use a wep passphrase, try doing it with your interface down.

Comment: is wpa2-psk.... is iwconfig no good for it ?

Comment: no, you will have to use wpa_supplicant to connect to a wpa2-psk AP

Answer (score 1):

Since you're trying to connect to an AP advertising WPA2-PSK, you will have to use wpa_supplicant.

There are GUI frontend apps to connect, you could try wicd or networkmanager.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is a good question indeed. As good of a question as of how the Linux kernel "knows" that a signal has been handled OK by just, returning from the SIGHANDLER function... But to the topic, to create instances that cannot run any more than X seconds, "timeout" is a handy shell-utility. But if you know programming, then you may want to "do the dirt" yourself, to be 100% sure nothing *should* get/be wrong. =)

If you are on a *nix-system, then, as stated in the beginning... The signal-framework can be very handy, and a lot of other stuff.